# An alias within a node module

Tags: node.js, webpack, path, node-modules, alias

I have a private made npm package that has a symbol `@` I'd like to use as an alias to use in my current project. Is this possible?

Example:

project structure

```
|-node_modules
      |
      |-@package_name
             |
             |-packagefile.js
|-src
   |
   |-srcfile.js
|
|-webpack.config.js
```

Now in:

packagefile.js

```
const v = require('@/srcfile.js')
```

Can webpack create an alias with the symbol `@` to lead to the `src` directory? I have functionality in this package I want to interact with my current project.

In my `webpack.config` I have:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
     alias: {
       '@': path.resolve(__dirname,'./src'),      
     }
  }
  ...
}
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have two packages here: the package in node_modules, which I'll refer to as "A", and the package under src, which I'll refer to as "B". B *depends on* A, so B can access A and whatever it exports. However, A does *not* depend on B. A cannot access anything in B. Package dependencies are one-way. You need to decide whether you want A to depend on B, or B to depend on A.

Answer (score 1):

I think your webpack config is effective for the root folder, not for node_module.
So I guess, The Package should have it own webpack config
like this

```
|-node_modules
      |
      |-@package_name
             |
             |-packagefile.js
             |-webpack.config.js
|-src
   |
   |-srcfile.js
|
|-webpack.config.js
```